# keyPress.which shows more codes than what barcode scanner outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, barcode, barcode-scanner

When I use a barcode scanner in a normal notepad, it scans a code like this: `2000000415369`.
When I create an input field in `HTML` and put focus into that field and scan a barcode, it still outputs the correct code.

Now when I create a javascript listener to capture the code, to make sure, in javascript, that the input came from a barcode scanner, the keyPress `event.which` string outputs a lot more characters than what is described above. I get this in my console output:

```
0|5|0|2|0|4|8|0|0|4|8|0|0|4|8|0|0|4|8|0|0|4|8|0|0|4|8|0|0|5|2|4|0|4|9|1|0|5|3|5|0|5|1|3|0|5|4|6|0|5|7|9|
```

where every keycode has been changed into its keyboard value. When you compare the two scanned codes, you'll see that the correct barcode is contained within the longer scanned code. Every correct character is separated by 3 additional numbers:

050 **2** 048 **0** 048 **0** 048 **0** 048 **0** 048 **0** 048 **0** 052 **4** 049 **1** 053 **5** 051 **3** 054 **6** 057 **9**

Does anybody have any clue what is going on here? I'm at a complete loss why the keyPress event would capture more numbers pressed than the input field. I also tested with a normal keyboard and typing would result in only the correct pressed character to be outputed to the console.

Below is the javascript code I use for capturing the keyPress event:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress',function(e){
    aScannedEan.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});

console.log(aScannedEan.join("|"));
```

Comment: I'm not certain why it's happening, but the additional number is the keycode of the number. I would imagine there's some oddity in the way the scanner is outputting the number in the field. Just as a guess, have you tried `keydown` or `keyup`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
 var current_keys = []; 
var str='';
 function checkKeyPress(event){
        current_keys.push(event.keyCode);
        setTimeout(interpret_keys, 500);
    }

    function interpret_keys (){
      var keys = -1,key, i = 0;
      for (i; i < current_keys.length; i++) {
        key = current_keys[i] - 48; 
        if(key >= 0 && key <= 9)  {
              keys = '' + key;
              str +=''+key; 
        }
      }
      keys = parseInt(keys); 
      current_keys = []; 
      checkKeyPress1(str);
    }
<body onkeypress="return checkKeyPress(event)" >
```

In the above code I was reading the number pressed by the user and navigating to that particular option.
Hope this helps.

Comment: this outputs: [18, 96, 101, 96, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 100, 104, 18, 96, 101, 98, 18, 96, 100, 105]. WHich basically is: ALT 050 2 048 0 ...
The same result I had in my original question, only now in keycodes instead of charcodes.